# JQuery - What method can I use to get this code to run without clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok this example code contains a button. Forget about the button, it does not exist, cannot be referenced and cannot be edited.

The buttons dont exist in this example - they merely represent another process. However the fields still need to be updated from values. Sorry I couldn't explain it better.

Answer:
http://jsfiddle.net/piezack/X8D4M/56/

Comment: I don't quite get the issue - do you want the link to update as you type into the field, or when you tab out of it, or...?

Comment: can you clarify? I'm not exactly sure what you want to trigger the bit of code. If not a user action, then what system action is happening?

Comment: You can try attaching a http://api.jquery.com/change/ event to your text field to update the link as text inside the input changes. Is the data in the input relevant to what the link will be changed to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the event to fire whenever the text inside the box changes, then I think you're best off using jquery's keyup event instead of blur:

```
$('#FormCustomObject6Name').keyup(
    function()
    {
        var x = $('#FormCustomObject6Id').val();

        $("a[href*='http://www.msn.com']").attr('href',('http://www.google.com/search?q='+ x));
        $('a#link').text('Link has been updated');   
    }
);
```

The only problem with this is that it won't catch instances where users enter data without using their keyboard (paste via right click, etc.).

Comment: Instead of using keyup would http://api.jquery.com/change/ take into account any other type of change in the value? Not just keyups.

Comment: Bind to both the keyup event and the onchange event: `$('#FormCustomObject6Name').bind('keyup change',  function() { ...` if keyup doesn't also trigger change.

Comment: Good try, but nothing is entered by the keyboard in this case. The button represents the input method, but it is actually much more complex and there is no button.

Comment: I'm assuming the input then is "calculator-style"? Where the buttons are pressed, and it causes a change in the textbox? Or is the value updated by some other means? ...Regardless, it sounds like you need to find the action that's causing the value to change, and latch on to that function.

Comment: @idb - so there is no button, there is no text field - what *is* there? What event **does** occur that indicates "a record has been chosen"? I don't mean "browser event", I mean what is this complex action that results in wanting to change the link?  I"m tempted to downvote the question because it is *so vague*.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `mouseover` event, say over the `button` or the `link`.

I changed this

```
$('.butter').mouseover(function(){
```

to have a mouseover the button.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/X8D4M/39/

Comment: This looks promising. Is there a way to have the mouseover event occur every time the link is moused over? It seems to only run once.

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger events on objects yourself manually by using `trigger(event)`.

So this might work for you:

```
$('button.butter').trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try just triggering a click?

```
$('button.butter').click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you're looking for.

```
$('#FormCustomObject6Name').trigger('blur');
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is probably not the most efficient solution, but if you use setInterval to check for the changed value you're guaranteed to cover all sources of the change.

```
setInterval(function(){
    var id = $('#FormCustomObject6Id').val();
    var name = x + $('#FormCustomObject6Name').val();
    if (id.length > 0 && name.length > 0){
        $("a[href*='http://www.msn.com']").attr('href',('http://www.google.com/search?q='+ id));
        $('a#link').text('Link has been updated');
    }
},500);
```